# How to add KMLlayer to Android GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

based on this link "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml" I have followed it until to the point where I have to type this code:

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
```

I'm having a red line in 'getMap()' and 'R.raw.kmlFile' and I can't understand what it's trying to say in the part where he says

***To import and render a KML dataset from a local resource, you need:

A GoogleMap object where the layer is to be rendered.
A local resource file containing the KML data.
A Context object, which is required to open a local resource file.***

Can you please guide me on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get map and then add a KML layer on top of it. Something like that:

```
...

private GoogleMap mMap;

...

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    ...
}

...

public void addKML() {
    KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
    layer.addLayerToMap();
}  
...
```

For details take a look at [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/KmlDemoActivity.java) file in [that](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) repo.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the getMap() error, you need to create a Google Map object and pass it in. The code Andrii provided would solve the problem.

To get rid of the error at 'R.raw.kmlFile', you need to create a raw folder.

Right-click the *res* folder, then go to *New* -> *Android resource directory*. Set the *Directory name* and *Directory type* as "raw", then click *OK*. [Here](https://hellotech633.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/create-add-raw-folder-in-android-studio/) is a more detailed guide.